# Paypal NVP TransanctionSearch with INVNUM doesn't return any payment informations

Tags: php, api, paypal, nvp

We are currently using Paypal NVP(`Version 54.0`) with the `TransanctionSearch` call/function to search for payments with specific invoice numbers. It was working since today morning.
We use the `TrasnactionSearch` with the parameters `STARTDATE` and `INVNUM`, but it doesn't return any payment informations anymore. It looks like it doesn't find the transaction, but when I do the same search on the paypal website, it works.

As far as I can see, there is currently no technical issue reported.

Does anyone else have this issue too?

Comment: This is the sort of thing you would need to submit directly to PayPal MTS.  You'll need to include transaction details for a transaction that includes the invoice parameter as well as request / response logs for the TransactionSearch request you're making that should include that transaction.

Comment: Yeah, i did this on friday via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask I hope, i'll get an answer in the next days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an issue in the paypal nvp api. I've reported it on a friday on this page: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask
It was fixed during weekend and now everything is fine.
I still dont have got any answer from the paypal support, but when someone have similar issues, then you should use the bug report form.